# how to change the name in flutter app in mobile app

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

what I am trying to do is I want change logo and name mobile app using flutter project

I import the https://github.com/creativetimofficial/argon-flutter this flutter project in git in my vs code but when I am run the flutter project in my vs code i want to change the logo and name in app.

how can we do that https://ibb.co/mzs5qS0 in this image when i run the project its showing in mobile app name argon-flutter but i want to rename

how can we do

plz let me out i am new in this flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Icon:**
Go to sites like appicon.co and convert your regular image to png and related ones. just select the appropriate platforms (like in this case make sure Android is selected) and download. Open the downloaded folder and open android folder inside it.

Got to your project folder, navigate to android>>app>>src>>main>>res. Right click on res and open in Explorer/folder.

Replace all mipmap folders with the one that you downloaded.

**For Label**

Change the name/label in AndroidManifest & pubspec.yaml

Comment: @V M when i right click on res then its showing many option which one i select in image u can see res click https://ibb.co/Rb4dmS8 and when i download the png using this one appicon.co then in android under four folder is there https://ibb.co/PT67NND

Comment: Can u help me out ??

Comment: When u right click on res, click on Reveal in Explorer, it will open in folder. Inside you will see mipmap folders, replace them with the the one you downloaded ->  ibb.co/PT67NND

Answer (score 1):

To change the App name you need to change it in android -> app -> main -> **AndroidManifest.xml** and change the **android label**. For your App Icon use this package [Flutter Launcher Icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)

```
android:label:"Your App name".
```